# Swingbuilder - application location centering

Tags: java, griffon, swingbuilder

I am creating an application using Griffon->SwingBuilder. I would like to able to center the application on the desktop.

I know we have the 'location: [x,y]' argument we can provide on application creation. Is there anyway to access desktop properties to calculate the center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For various reasons you cannot do it inline.  Here is one way to center

```
import java.awt.*
import groovy.swing.*

sb = new SwingBuilder()
sb.build {
  f = frame(pack:true) {
      label "<html>" + (("This is a very long label."*3) + "<BR>")*5
  }
  Point cp = GraphicsEnvironment.localGraphicsEnvironment.centerPoint
  f.location = new Point((int)(cp.x - f.width), (int) (cp.y - f.height))
  f.show()
}
```

The reason you cannot set it in the attributes is that when the attributes are evaluated a child node has not yet been created or stored anywhere.  One alternative is to set it as part of the child content block:

```
  frame(show:true) 
  {
      label "<html>" + (("This is a very long label."*3) + "<BR>")*5
      current.pack()
      Point cp = GraphicsEnvironment.localGraphicsEnvironment.centerPoint
      current.location = new Point((int)(cp.x -current.width/2), (int)(cp.y - current.height/2))
  }
```

(current is a meta-variable for the containing node).

Comment: Thanks alot - I tried the 2nd option and it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One of Swing features is, that it remembers last position and size (if resizable)